# How to use &gt; in react jsx?

Tags: reactjs, tsx

```
{crumbs.map((item, idx) => {
    return (<Link href={item.href}>{item.label}</Link>)
})}
```

I want to add an optional `&gt;` if `idx < crumbs.length` -- I keep getting parsing errors no matter what I try.

Comment: you want crumbs like this: crumb1 > crumb2 > ... > crumbn, right? and you want to add render a special character > when idx < crumbs.length?

Comment: Please include the error then (in your question) and also show the example where it fails. Your snippet does not match your question.

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually doing without a [mre] but likely you're inside braces therefore just writing plain JS and should simply write `">"`. It's important when writing JSX to keep track of whether you're in a JS or XML context.

Answer (score -1):

```
{crumbs.reduce((out, item, i) => {
    if (i > 0) {
        // Need to use span tag to set key property in result code
        out.push(<span>{'>'}</span>)
    }

    out.push(<Link href={item.href}>{item.label}</Link>)

    return out
}, [])}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  return (
      <nav className={style.breadCrumbs}>
        <>
            <Link href="/"><img src="/home.svg" alt="" /></Link>
            <span>&gt;</span>
        </> 
      {crumbs.map((item, idx) => {
            if (idx === crumbs.length-1 ) {
                return <span>{item.label}</span>
            } else {
                return <><Link href={item.href}>{item.label}</Link> <span>&gt;</span></> 
            }
        })}
      </nav>
  )
```

Only problem is I need to add a key here somehow.

Comment: If you have a static-item list that does not change, you can use the index, otherwise, find a better property for the key. The item.href is probably unique so ... try this. Item.label can also be used as the key btw.